# Hide Action Bar in a Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I am creating the framework for an app and wish to hide the action bar for the login activity. The app is going to be entirely composed of fragments because they are awesome.

I can hide the action bar fine for my activity, but every time I run the app I see my inflated blank fragment and default action bar for about 2 seconds before it manages to inflate the login fragment.

Any idea on how / where I should hide the action bar, (whilst keeping my framework) to stop this from happening?

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new LoginFragment();
}
```

}

SingleFragmentActivity.java

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(this instanceof LoginActivity){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = createFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, parent, false);

    return v;
}
```

}

I originally had SingleFragmentActivity extend FragmentActivity and did this in the if statement:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But I've got a feeling that's just a different way of doing the same thing

Edit:

I have also tried setting the fragment_activity to use a different style but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay after a few hours I think I have found the solution to keeping fragments in place for everything and removing the action bar (for all devices) for the launch activity only:

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.company.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.company.app.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Where the style is defined as like so:

```
   <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

That took a while to figure out because there is no Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar , the action bar is basically known as the title bar in older APIs, and when I applied that style to the activity itself (which I thought was the only way of using dynamic themes) it doesn't seem to work at all.

So hopefully this simple solution will keep the action bar for any other activities and it may help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
if(this instanceof LoginActivity) {
    if (getActionBar().isShowing()) getActionBar().hide();
} else {
    if (getActionBar().isShowing()) getActionBar().hide();
}
```

**or**

```
if(this instanceof LoginActivity){
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
} else {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude but I think I have solved it with my other answer, if you notice that's what I was using originally, but the base fragment container was being thrown up on screen in super.onCreate() method first for a couple of seconds

Answer (score 3):

Daniel Wilson's comment above does work but just a minor difference in how I did it.
I did not define style at all, all I did in AndroidManifext.xml is that I added this to my activity:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

So, I did not have to redefine style for NoActionBar, I just added it from Theme.AppCompat

Comment: Yeah I believe that's a relatively newer addition to the app compat library than when this question was first posted, although I could be wrong! Seems like a good solution though

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code in Activity.onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hiding the title bar has to happen before the view is created
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ...
}
```